# Fetch company with all deactive jobs

Tags: sql-server

`tbl_posting_job_info`

[image: tbl_posting_job_info]

`tbl_company_info`

```
company_id     companyname
---------------------------
1              XYZ
4              PQR
8              LMN
```

Now I want an information of a company which doesn't have even a single 'active' job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  *
from    tbl_company_info c
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    tbl_posting_job_info j
        where   j.company_id = c.company_id
                and j.status = 'active'
        )
```

Comment: where is `active-deactive` values filteration...?

Comment: Missed that, added to answer now

Comment: Somehow it works..I will make it work for my requirement further..thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    tbl_company_info a
where   Isnull((
        select  count(*)
        from    tbl_posting_job_info b
        where   a.company_id = b.company_id
                and a.status = 'active'
        ),0) = 0
```